# MySQL joining from a relations table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select some data from two tables but its slightly more complicated than I first thought. I have two tables (`content` & `relations`).

```
    content
    +----+-----------+--------------------+--------------+
    | id | elementId |       title        |  field_body  |
    +----+-----------+--------------------+--------------+
    |  1 |         1 | test title         | test body    |
    |  2 |         2 | another title      | another body |
    |  3 |         3 | category 10        | null         |
    |  4 |         4 | sub category 20    | null         |
    +----+-----------+--------------------+--------------+


    relations
    +----+----------+----------+-----------+
    | id | sourceId | targetId | sortOrder |
    +----+----------+----------+-----------+
    |  1 |        2 |        3 |         1 |
    |  2 |        2 |        4 |         2 |
    +----+----------+----------+-----------+
```

The way the tables are setup is as follows,
I create an "article" on my website that consists of the following:

- article title
- article body
- article main category
- article sub category

I need to fetch each article and the associated main and sub category from the table `content`

So for example it would bring back this row ->

`another title, another body, category10, sub category 20`

because in the relations table the source id is 2 which is linked to the elementId of the article and the targetId is the ID of the category to associate with the article.

What would be the best way to approach doing this ? i've tried several different query's to get this to work but it doesn't seem possible

Comment: Hint: `JOIN` ...

Comment: where is your tried query share it

Comment: I wouldn't design tables like this first of all. Its very confusing and if it gets bigger, you would have problems. Why won't you have a table called Categories with different types of categories in it. You can than relate each Article to category it belongs to by having FK of this category in Article table.

Comment: The design of the table wasn't my choice and it's completely out of my control and can't be changed unfortunately otherwise I would of done exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in ur **relations** table data, which is probably based on adjacency list model:

record with id == 2 must have sourceId field == 3:

```
relations
    +----+----------+----------+-----------+
    | id | sourceId | targetId | sortOrder |
    +----+----------+----------+-----------+
    |  1 |        2 |        3 |         1 |
    |  2 |        3 |        4 |         2 |
    +----+----------+----------+-----------+
```

After that u can try this sql:

```
select
c.id,
c.title as article_title,
c.field_body as article_body,
c1.title as article_main_category,
c2.title as article_sub_category
from
content c
join relations as r1 on r1.sourceId = c.elementId
join content as c1 on c1.elementId = r1.targetId
join relations as r2 on r2.sourceId = c1.elementId
join content as c2 on c2.elementId = r2.targetId
```

If relations table data is ok, and sortOrder field makes sense, then we can try this sql query:

```
select
c.id,
c.title as article_title,
c.field_body as article_body,
c1.title as article_main_category,
c2.title as article_sub_category
from
content c
join relations as r1 on r1.sourceId = c.elementId and r1.sortOrder = 1
join content as c1 on c1.elementId = r1.targetId
join relations as r2 on r2.sourceId = c.elementId and r2.sortOrder = 2
join content as c2 on c2.elementId = r2.targetId
```

Comment: The sourceId is the elementId of the article that the category is associated with, because each article has a `Main category` and a `sub category` the Main category is the item with the sortOrder == 1 and the sub category is the item with the sortOrder == 2 if that makes sense ?

Comment: the second query seems to of worked perfectly, thanks!